# How to send a push notification after a button is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I currently have an iOS App that is already set up to receive push notifications.  What I'm trying to do is, after a user presses the 'Join' button, I want to send them a "Welcome" push notification.  Any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy.

`AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil))
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("Local notification received (tapped, or while app in foreground): \(notification)")
}
```

Then in your action:

```
@IBAction func welcomeMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Welcome to the app!" // text that will be displayed in the notification

    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    notification.userInfo = ["title": "Title", "UUID": "12345"]         
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Now if the app is in the background, you see an Push notification.  If it's in the foreground then your `didReceiveLocalNotification` fires instead.  Tapping on the notification launches your app to the foreground and fires `didReceiveLocalNotification` also.

Answer (score 0):

On YouTube, Jared Davidson offers some great iOS tutorials.
He has two on notifications:

This one is just what you need:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqJFJzUPpcI

...and there's one for remote notifications (not with a button)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBw5tuTvKd4

Comment: Note: AppCoda has an **amazing** tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/

Comment: I'm actually looking for push notifications not regular notifications but thanks anyways.